# Getting reCaptcha to work over Ajax with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, recaptcha

I have a form that validates and posts with Ajax, or more specifically, with `$.post()`.

At one point, there is a reCaptcha. This form worked fine when I did not use `$.post()` but posted the old-fashioned way (with a page refresh), just for reference.

Converting the form requires that I changed all `$_POST`'s to `$_REQUEST`'s. However, this doesn't remedy the reCaptcha problem, so I've left that intact. Here is the reCaptcha PHP code inside registerPost.php:

```
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "dropbeatsnotbombs";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
echo "Error";
}
else {
   //post form
}
```

Here's the jQuery handling the form posting:

```
$.post('php/registerPost.php', $('#registerPost').serialize(), function(data){
                if(data == "Error")
                {
                    $('#caErr').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location.replace("//main page");
                }
            });
```

> Note: the reCaptcha *seems* to return as false, since the form will not submit when everything is filled in correctly.

What I want to do is show an error if the reCaptcha was entered wrong, and post if it was entered right, all asynchronously.

Any help?

Comment: +1 "dropbeatsnotbombs"? Nice... :)

Comment: are you sure that the eveything in the form was valid??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. I need to go read the API documentation for $.post(), but my first guess is that since the form is not really submitted, the $_POST array is not being populated, so when you use values like `$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]`, it's just an empty field. Again, I need to go verify that, but that is my hunch.

**EDIT:**

Looks like I was wrong. I compared what you have to both the API and an older script I had, and what you are doing should be fine. The only difference I see is that you are passing this as data:

```
$('#registerPost').serialize()
```

whereas my script was passing this:

```
$('#form').serializeArray()
```

It could be as simple as that...